# Why are the @Configuration classes not being run in Spring Boot tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot `@Configuration` class that's located at `com.app.config` and a controller located at `com.app.controller` and my test (in the tests directory) is at `com.app.controller`. When I run it, the configuration class is never used.

```
package com.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.app")
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {

        //The breakpoint here is never called!
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan({"com.app","com.app.config"})
public class TestAumController {

    //...elided...

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void testController() throws Exception {
        //..edlided...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ComponentScan` is for `@Configuration` classes. Try replacing that in your test class with `@SpringBootTest`, which loads and configures the application context

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes.

In Configuration file, add `@ComponentScan("Your Package path")`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;               

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.app")
public class ValidationConfig {
```

In Test File, add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationClass.class)`

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ValidationConfig.class)
public class TestAumController {
```

For more Info, You can refer this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).